# group/ungroup appears linked to hide/unhide function

Tags: excel, vba

I am sorry if someone has asked this in the past.  I was not able to find a solution, though.

I have several modules in a worksheet.  My data is organized into groups with the excel outline function.  I have 4 levels.  I also have code that sorts through the data and selectively hides rows.   All of this works fine. The problem is my last line, which is the following:

```
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=3
```

Executing this line results in "unhiding" all the rows I just hid.

Not including this line - the macro works and the rows are hid correctly.

If the line is at the beginning of the macro, the macro still "ungroups" to level 4 to execute.

Can anyone explain what might be causing this behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: there is probably more eloquent explanations out there, but it just seems to be XL's behavior to show hidden rows when showing outline levels. Why don't you show the level you want, then hide the rows?

Comment: Scott,  Thank you very much for your suggestion.  However, as I indicated in my question: If the line is at the beginning of the macro, the macro still "ungroups" to level 4 to execute.  The grouping is not maintained - the action of hiding rows opens up all the levels.  I am not sure what the work-around is.

Comment: Here is a clue (is this a bug in excel?).  I removed the above line (ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=3) from the macro entirely and ran the macro.  It worked as expected and hid the rows it was supposed to hide.  It left the worksheet opened to level 4.  I then clicked on the "3" button to collapse the groups to level 3.  When I opened up one of the groups and examined it, the rows that were once hid, were no longer hid.  The action of collapsing the groups had the effect of un-hiding the rows.  Very, very weird.

Comment: SOLVED:I used a filter to achieve the same effect as hiding/unhiding:

ActiveSheet.Range("I5").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<" & "4", Operator:=xlAnd

Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=3

Initially, the filter was "hiding" my level 1 groups. However, the work-around to this was to create an artificial header row with blank rows above and below it. I made the row heights very small, and the filter is essentially invisible to the user.

I use a button to show or hide these requirements. It ended up being a straight-forward workaround.

Comment: Aerogal31, I'm having the same problem, but using a filter instead of hiding/unhiding doesn't fix it.  Every time I do ShowLevels, the filter is bypassed and every row is shown.  Not that straightforward for me.